# Batch. Mass renaming files in the folder and all sub-folders

Tags: batch, batch-file

I try to rename all files in folder and sub-folders by removing the "-min" part from each filename with help of batch-scripting under win7

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CD F:\Mega.Pack-128x128\textures\
FOR /R %%A in (.*)-min.png DO REN "%%A-min.png" "%%A.png"
```

Looks like something is wrong here with SET parameter I guess, so I try to do it like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CD F:\Mega.Pack-128x128\textures\
For /R %%G in (*-min.png) DO (
    SET "oldname=%%G"
    SET "newname=!oldname:~0,-8!.png"
    REN "!oldname!" "!newname!"
)
```

but all I get is errors.
When I echo last instruction from the loop it gives me proper paths. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When renaming a file, you cannot include the folder path in the target name. You can use `%%~nxG` to get the file name and extension without the path. You don't need the oldname variable - you can simply use `%%G`. You can eliminate a line and do the string manipulation directly in the REN statement.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CD F:\Mega.Pack-128x128\textures\
For /R %%G in (*-min.png) DO (
    SET "newname=%%~nxG"
    REN "%%G" "!newname:~0,-8!.png"
)
```

Note that the above will fail if any part of the file path includes the `!` character because FOR variable expansion occurs before delayed expansion, so it will corrupt the value. Any `!` can be preserved by making sure delayed expansion is disabled when the FOR variable is expanded. This requires toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
cd F:\Mega.Pack-128x128\textures\
for /r %%G in (*-min.png) do (
  set "oldpath=%%G"
  set "newname=%%~nxG"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!oldpath!" "!newname:~0,-8!.png"
  endlocal
)
```